# Windows Phone 7 Dynamic Listbox and RSS feed problems

Tags: c#, silverlight, rss, listbox, windows-phone

I am having a huge problem with doing this, and I am hoping someone can take me under their wing and help guide me through this.

My problem is not knowing how to dynamically add more items to the listbox after getting the first set of 15 through my custom made RSS feed, tied to my website, into my windows phone 7.

I am thinking of limiting my RSS feed to 15 items, so that those who subscribe will not be inundated with thousands of items in the feed.

However, this poses a problem when coding for my phone. If I cap my RSS feed to the 15 most recent items, how can I obtain the prior ones outside of these 15, and the other problem, how to load them?

I already have my RSS feed classes, and I can successfully obtain my rss feed in my phone. That is not the problem. Again stated -- once I load my initial 15 items in the windows phone 7, how can I load additional sets of 15, if I keep my RSS items in my website xml kept to 15 items at a time (again, so that I don't have an RSS feed with 1000s of items every time a person loads it)

Any help is appreciated.

Page CS:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RssService.GetRssItems(
            WindowsPhoneBlogPosts,
            (items) => { listbox.ItemsSource = items; },
            (exception) => { MessageBox.Show(exception.Message); },
            null
            );
    }
```

Page XAML:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="listbox" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="listbox_SelectionChanged" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image x:Name="aaa"  Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Width="60" Source="{Binding Url}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding PublishedDate}" Foreground="Green" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding PlainSummary}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Same page Xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle1" TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                            <Button x:Name="thebutton" Content="Button" Visibility="{Binding LoadMore}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: Ok, so you have the feed and that's not the problem, so what is it??

Comment: The problem is that (and maybe my lack of understand of RSS feeds) if I cap my RSS feed to 15 items.. and say in a month from now I have 500 items, but I still only show the 15 most recent.. how could I get my phone to show the prior 485 whenever I want to hit the "Load More" button? (breaking them up into small chunks of say.. 15 each load?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up about [data virtualization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/16/virtualizing-data-in-windows-phone-7-silverlight-applications.aspx), and about how to [load data while scrolling](http://danielvaughan.org/post/Scroll-Based-Data-Loading-in-Windows-Phone-7.aspx), and lastly about the whole concept behind [virtuailization](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2009/09/06/ui-virtualization-vs-data-virtualization.aspx) in general.

Comment: so in essence I can have my RSS feed have 1000s of items in it on my website. Not all 1000 will be loaded upon the call from the phone, and I can have them appear as needed as I scroll through the listbox. Is this correct?

Comment: You have two options -- a) Load all data with a single request, and let virtualization handle the rendering. Or b) Load x items and when scrolling down to the end, do another request to load more. But 1000 items isn't that much, so I don't see why you wouldn't just get all of them with the first request.

Comment: I should mention that I am loading pictures, so I think I will have to go with the latter option

Comment: Doesn't make much of a difference. You can just lazy-load the pictures, so they're first rendered when you scroll down to them. Google for "LowProfileImageLoader"